# How to get the state from redux-saga select()?

Tags: select, redux-saga, immutable.js

the saga like below.

```
function *callUserAuth(action) {
    const selectAllState = (state) => state;
    const tmp = yield select(selectAllState);
    console.log(tmp);
}
```

the console show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5NDL.png)

how can i get state like 
getState["userLoginReducer","isLogin"] in redux ?

i had tried to code like below.

```
const tmp = yield select(selectAllState._root.entries);
```

but error is

```
index.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Immutable.js for your redux state.

The `select` effect doesn't convert your Immtuable structure to plain javascript. So you need to use methods of Immutable to get to the values you want. To get the whole Immutable state and then convert it to plain javascript object you can do:

```
function *callUserAuth(action) {
    const selectAllState = (state) => state;
    const tmp = yield select(selectAllState);
    console.log(tmp.toJS());
}
```

But generally you will probably want to have selectors to get a subset like the `isLogin` value. In that case you can do this instead:

```
function *callUserAuth(action) {
    const getIsLogin = (state) => state.get('userLoginReducer').get('isLogin');
    const isLogin = yield select(getIsLogin);
    console.log(isLogin);
}
```

Comment: @kennymarx0 np, if it works for you please mark the answer as correct :)